# PHP 7 x64 ODBC Error Connecting to MSSQL Database

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, sqlsrv, php-7

Getting the following error when testing an upgrade to PHP7 x64:

*odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified*

I've installed the following:

- PHP 7.0.0 x64
- Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server x64
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable x64
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable x86
- The (thread-safe) preview of the PHP 7 MSSQL drivers: https://github.com/Azure/msphpsql

I have uncommented/added the following lines of my phpini:

- extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll (uncommented)
- extension=php_odbc.dll (added)
- extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts.dll (added)
- extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts.dll (added)

Things to consider:

- I can see that the modules are indeed loaded in phpinfo.
- I've added the ODBC connection and can see it in System DSN.
- I am successfully able to connect via sqlsrv_connect() but not odbc_connect(), which is what all our previous PHP 5.6 scripts are using.

Can't seem to find the answer anywhere else. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved my own issue.

Turns out, the ODBC_CONNECT string uses an explicit DSN name and not a database, apparently...

Previously my ODBC Connect string was $conn = odbc_connect('DB',$DBUSER, $DBPASS)
and my ODBC Data Source was "SERVERNAME"

Once I changed the ODBC Data Source name to match the DB name, it worked.